# Why doesn't windows desktop broadcast UDP?

Tags: java, networking, udp, cross-platform, broadcast

Alright, so my application is a peer to peer chat application, designed for LAN communication. Discovery is done by UDP broadcasting the ip & port at the UDP broadcast address (255.255.255.255). I'm running it on three platforms at once when testing: ubuntu (VM via VirtualBox, and it's connected to the network via VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter), windows 10 (my development platform, and is "directly" connected to the "main" network, my router, via my wifi network adapter), and on android, where it is connected "directly" as well.

Desktop & Ubuntu share exactly the same jar executable, and android shares the same networking model, which is responsible for finding peers on the network and establishing connections, as well as broadcasting the client upon starting.

I'll say again that **the three platforms I'm running it from share exactly the same networker.**

However, when I'm running my application from android and/or VM first, and then afterwards on windows 10, I discovered that the windows client will NOT broadcast itself on the broadcast address, as confirmed by my later testing with wireshark. Android and the VM WILL show up as broadcasting on the broadcasting address, while windows 10 won't.

The code for creating the broadcast socket that sends and receives UDP broadcasts is as follows, and it's handled by one specific thread, with no other thread having access:

```
public FindPeersBroadcasterRunnable() {
        try {
            broadcastSocket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.UDP_DECLARE_PEERS_PORT);
            broadcastSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[Constants.MAX_PEER_NOTIFY_LENGTH], Constants.MAX_PEER_NOTIFY_LENGTH);
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

It's while-worthy to note that Constants.UDP_DECLARE_PEERS_PORT is 13100.

Also, these are the results from WireShark (with my IP hidden to protect my privacy):

[image: Wireshark network sniffing results]

Both android & the VM are broadcasting correctly, and I've checked manually that I'm using the correct adapter (I'm using my wifi adapter on windows).

Any clues and help **why am I not broadcasting** from windows while from the other two platforms it's fine would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Broadcast is an old, deprecated way to do things. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on a LAN, including hosts not interested (routers, printers, etc.), and it wastes bandwidth. That is why broadcasting has been eliminated from IPv6, so your application cannot be ported to IPv6. The modern way to do it is with multicast, which only interrupts the hosts interested in receiving the multicast. Broadcast cannot be routed, but we have multicast routing (very different than unicast routing), so multicast can be routed, too.

Comment: @RonMaupin Could you redirect me to a resource to get started so I can port the networking portion of the application to multicast before the official release of the application? Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely solved: I had to bind the adapter address I'm using in order for the UDP Socket to broadcast correctly, as such:

```
broadcastSocket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.UDP_DECLARE_PEERS_PORT, InetAddress.getByName(IP_HERE));
```

Comment: On Windows, broadcast packets aren't sent out on every interface.  They are only sent on the primary interface... and I don't recall how Windows determines which that is.  It's a real problem!  Been driving me crazy for decades now.  :-)

Comment: @Brad It really is a problem! Thankfully java has got my back and I can declare explicitly the inetaddress of the interface I want to use.